# What do you call dough with fat?

Tags: phrase-request

What do you call dough with fat (as opposed to bread dough or noodle dough)? In Russian, we call it "сдобное тесто". It may contain things like butter, margarine, eggs, vegetable oil. I guess some old school folks would add actual animal fat. Is it "pastry dough" or something?

Comment: Dough is just dough, whether with or without fat. A preceding word would identify the type. Bread dough can have fat. So can pasta dough if it contains eggs.

Comment: Personally I would call it a "rich dough".  In food, "rich" typically means "has lots of fat".

Comment: When bread dough has butter or other things added to make it 'special', it is sometimes called 'enriched dough'. Pastry dough, which has to contain fat, is just 'pastry dough'.

Answer (score 0):

Pastry is made with a low-gluten flour, shortening (like butter or suet) and just a little water.  Pastry may contain egg, but it never contains yeast.  Pastry is quite unlike bread dough.

Many doughs contain some fat or oil.  Foccacia for example contains olive oil. Dough with some fat to add smoothness or softer bread is normal enough not to have a special name. It is a normal additive to the dough.

If there is a special recipe, English is quite happy to borrow words from other languages. I'd be happy to read about "Russian sdobnoye dough" if it was explained to me in in the context.

Comment: What is ^H^H^H supposed to be? Is that formatting gone wrong?

Comment: Back in the good old days, computer terminals would sometimes produce the wrong code for "delete" which would result in "ctrl-H" appearing instead of text being deleted.  Sometimes it would result in slips in which the poster would try to delete the honest word, but since the delete key wasn;t interpreted as "delete", the slip would be posted publically. In parody of this, using ^H means "The first word is the honest one, ^H means delete". It's a joke that is probably 30 years past its best before date.

Comment: @gotube It's a [Unix meme](http://wooledge.org/~greg/%5EH.html). Goes right back to Unix via terminals linked to minicomputers and mainframes. Each Ctrl-H key press deletes a preceding character and allows retype. On pressing ENTER the edited line is sent to the computer, but the display screen shows the key presses. ^ is CTRL. Example: `At 5:00 I plan to get drunk^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^Hgo home and rest`. The ^H sequence represents a strikethrough. The meme/joke is to use them intentionally and visibly in text such as emails.  I think James K might be a Unix person like me.

Comment: @JamesK - you still see it on Slashdot. Maybe I'm ruining my image admitting I post on there.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey +5 insightful

Comment: Let me sneak a sly mention in for Bolo do Caco, the Madeiran flat bread rolls made with sweet potato dough. Simply scrumptious (OK moderator, delete it!)